# Java Coding assignment explanation

Tags: java

I'm working on a project and one of the assignments is below. I don't really need an answer, but an explanation of what my teacher is looking for.

This is what he gave me:

Write a wholly creative program to demonstrate that you understand how to print:

-doubles with control of decimals

-ints in binary, base-10, and base-16

-Strings, chars and Booleans

Use comments liberally to explain your code.

HINTS

```
System.out.printf("%X", 255);     //outputs FF
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(255)); //outputs FF
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(7));     //outputs 111
```

Comment: It seems he wants you to create variables of type double, int, String, char, and Boolean. After doing so, you must print them all. In addition, the ints need to be printed in binary (1010101), base 10 (the usual), and base 16 (afd12ed). Also, the double should be printed with more than one precision of decimals (1.23 and 1.2 for example).

Comment: Dude, the only one who can explain what your teacher is looking for is **your teacher**, unless.... do we have any mind readers out there in SO-land?

Comment: You should ask your teacher what they're looking for; they know the answer to that much better than we will. If you didn't understand the assignment, you should have asked for clarification. Now's the time to fix that and ask your instructor to explain. Good luck.

Comment: My Teacher doesn't respond for days. That's why I have asked.

Comment: *My Teacher doesn't respond for days.* Maybe get a new teacher? He does realize that you're paying him to teach, right?

Comment: You are not asking SO for writing the code for you, good. However, asking for an explanation of other peoples meaning is offtopic. You yourself could however re-read the training material (text book, script, tutorial) which you handled most recently in class. That could give you a meta answer, not what the teacher wants, but what he could sensibly want at this time through your lessons.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot be sure how you have to deliver your solution and of course you should ask your teacher. (Is it a single print method, multiple ones, and so on). But lets assume it is multiple methods.

> doubles with control of decimals

A method `printDouble(double d, int decimals)`

Example Output:

```
 printDouble(3.1415, 2) -> 3.14
 printDouble(3.1415, 0) -> 3
 printDouble(3.1415, 1) -> 3.1
```

> ints in binary, base-10, and base-16

A method `printInt(int n, int base)`

Example Output:

```
printInt(10, 2)  -> 1010
printInt(10, 10) -> 10
printInt(10, 16) -> A
```

> Strings...

`printString(String s)`

Example Output

```
printString("hello") -> hello
printString("")      ->       //nothing
printString("a")     -> a
```

> ...chars...

`printChar(char c)`

Example Output:

```
printChar('a') -> a
printChar('x') -> x
```

> ...and Booleans

`printBoolean(Boolean b)`

Example Output:

```
printBoolean(true)   -> true
printBoolean(false)  -> false
printBoolean(1 == 1) -> true
```

You can also combine them all in one single method. The hints are probably there to tell you that Java does this by itself. Now i'm not really sure if you have to **implement that functionality yourself** or make appropriate use of Java's methods, so maybe ask for clarifications.